# Why when I upload a new jar to AWS EC2 I do not see the changes in the functionalities

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I have a question, I have tried to make changes to the rest service made with SpringBoot and deploy it in EC2 with a new jar generated with mvn install -DskipTests but when running it with docker-compose up I don't see that the functionality of the service has changed. I have tried restarting the EC2 instance but nothing happens ... Is there a special way to upload a change to EC2 or do I have to do some more step that I don't know about?

I have searched the internet but I can't find the answer, that's why I come here to ask.

The change I am making is in the expiration date of a user, I have tried to change it to months, more days or others, but I do not see reflected the changes in the functionality of the service when I generate and upload a new jar with the changes (obviously before I brought the changes from github). The strange thing is that I test it locally (on my computer) and these changes in the rest service work perfectly, but when uploading it to EC2, no changes are seen.

I hope you can help me, in advance, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point I am just assuming you have:

- a Dockerfile
- a JAR <-- that you modify
- a docker-compose.yaml file

You ran once `docker-compose up -d` to start **and build** your service. You need to run `docker-compose up -d --build` for any subsequent changes to your JAR or Dockerfile otherwise docker-compose will just use the already built image. You can check that with `docker image ls`